# PHP - Method in interface that accepts two integers

Tags: php, oop, interface, observer-pattern, method-signature

I'm trying to understand the Observer pattern. So far it's going good, I understand how things work and such.

But I have a question. In **Head First: Design Patterns** book, There's an example of a weather station program.

- `WeatherData` class is the `Subject`
- `CurrentConditionDisplay` and `StatisticsDisplay` are the observers

I've implemented all the code needed. But I always get this error:

> Declaration of CurrentConditionDisplay::update() must be compatible
>   with ObserverInterface::update()

Now I know what causes this error is that `update()` method in the interface is different from concrete classes that implements it in terms of parameters.

But in `CurrentConditionDisplay` class I have `update($temp, $humidity)` in the interface I have `update()`. I mean how to specify that `update()` method in one class takes two parameters (temp and humidity) and in another class it takes (temp and pressure) ?

Is there any solution instead of doing `update(SubjectInterface $subject)` in the `ObserverInterface` ?

Here's my code:

**Interfaces:**

```
interface SubjectInterface
{
    public function registerSubscriber(ObserverInterface $observerInterface);
    public function removeSubscriber(ObserverInterface $observerInterface);
    public function notifySubscriber();
}

interface ObserverInterface
{
    public function update();
}

interface DisplayInterface
{
    public function display();
}
```

**Classes: **

*WeatherData*

```
class WeatherData implements SubjectInterface
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $observers = [];

    protected $temp;
    protected $humidity;
    protected $pressure;

    public function registerSubscriber(ObserverInterface $observer)
    {
        $this->observers[] = $observer;
    }

    public function removeSubscriber(ObserverInterface $observer)
    {
        $i = array_search($this->observers, $observer);
        if ($i) {
            unset($this->observers[$i]);
        }
    }

    public function notifySubscriber()
    {
        foreach ($this->observers as $observer) {
            /** @var $observer ObserverInterface */
            $observer->update();
        }
    }

    public function setValues($temp, $humidity, $pressure)
    {
        $this->temp = $temp;
        $this->humidity = $humidity;
        $this->pressure = $pressure;
        $this->notifySubscriber();
    }
}
```

*CurrentConditionDisplay*

```
class CurrentConditionDisplay implements ObserverInterface, DisplayInterface
{
    protected $temp;
    protected $humidity;

    public function __construct(SubjectInterface $subject) {
        $subject->registerSubscriber($this);
    }

    public function display()
    {
        if(isset($this->temp) && isset($this->humidity)) {
            echo sprintf("CURRENT:<br>Temp: %d, Humidity: %d <br>", $this->temp, $this->humidity);
        }
    }

    public function update($new_temp, $new_humidity)
    {
        $this->temp = $new_temp;
        $this->humidity = $new_humidity;
        $this->display();
    }

}
```

*StatisticDisplay*

```
class StatisticDisplay implements ObserverInterface, DisplayInterface
{
    protected $temp;
    protected $pressure;

    public function __construct(SubjectInterface $subject) {
        $subject->registerSubscriber($this);
    }

    public function display()
    {
        if(isset($this->temp) && isset($this->pressure)) {
            return sprintf("STATISTIC:<br>Ration: %d <br>", $this->temp / $this->pressure);
        }
    }

    public function update($new_temp, $new_pressure)
    {
        $this->temp = $new_temp;
        $this->humidity = $new_pressure;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just an addition to the code you posted: You are implementing the Observer/Subject pattern somehow wrong.

The `Subject::register()` method (`WeatherData::registerSubscriber()`) should be used to actually *add* an Observer to a Subject. This should happen in some sort of Controller - and NOT in the Observer itself. Question yourself: How could an Observer be self registering to a Subject? This **won't** work:

```
public function __construct( SubjectInterface $subject ) {
    $subject->registerSubscriber($this);
}
```

Instead it should be the Subject which passes itself to the Observer. In other words: 
Your actual Subject (that gets monitored by the Observer), notifies *every* Observer.

```
// This class `implements SubjectInterface` */
public function notifySubscriber()
{
    foreach ($this->observers as $observer) {
        /** @var $observer ObserverInterface */
        $observer->update( $this ); // HERE WE HAND OVER THE SUBJECT TO THE OBSERVER
    }
}
```

Then, in your Observer, you should receive the Subject

```
public function update( Subjectinterface $subject )
{
    if ( "bar" === $this->foo() )
        // do something if the Subject has the desired state
}
```

This means two things:

1. Your Subject doesn't need to know of the amount nor the type of Observer. It just knows it got some and that it needs to notify them when it changes its state somehow.
2. Every Observer needs to decide if it should run and react on the state change - or not.

Overall I suggest [reading a bit more in detail](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer) about that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your method inside `CurrentConditionDisplay::update()` is this

```
public function update($new_temp, $new_humidity)
```

while you are `implement`ing the `ObserverInterface::update()` method which should look like this:

```
public function update();
```

And when PHP tells you that

> Declaration of `CurrentConditionDisplay::update()` must be compatible with `ObserverInterface::update()`

then it is telling you that your methods must match - in name, accessibility (`public|protected|private`) and arguments.

So your interface needs to have a different method if you want its implementing class to have arguments:

```
public function update( $new_temp, $new_humidity )
```

Comment: I've edited the title, Please take a look again. Thanks.

Comment: First: Please read my answer in detail. Second, I edited the answer so you can follow up easier.

Comment: So how can I specify that update function takes two integers ?

Comment: Your `interface` needs to define them. You are **implementing** _exactly_ what your interface (the RECIPE) says. If the interface has no variables for that method, then the implementing class is not allowed to have any as well. See php.net